# ConTeXt: Footnotes disappear in custom makeup

Tags: footnotes, context

I can't figure out how to make footnotes appear in a custom makeup. Footnotes seem to disappear regardless of vertical alignment or header/footer state. I've tried most of the makeup options listed on the ["setupmakeup" wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup) and I can't get anything to work.

Minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[S6][S6]

\starttext

This footnote \footnote{appears normally}

\definemakeup[custom]

\startcustommakeup
  This footnote \footnote{does not}
\stopcustommakeup

\stoptext
```

Comment: I think you should separate your edit from your question, send it as answer and accept it.

Comment: The makeup page is meant for cover pages, etc. That is the reason the footnotes are ignored by default

Comment: @Aditya OK, that makes sense, thanks. I've been using makeup pages to vertically center my slides. I might have to look into other arrangements in the long term.

Comment: For slides, you can simply define `\define\startslide{\vfill}`, `\define\stopslide{\vfill\page}` to vertically center the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only give a workaround with local footnotes, not convenient if you have to repeat your makeup. It might help you to play with setupmakeup, since the footnote shows.

```
\setuppapersize[S6][S6]
\starttext

This footnote \footnote{appears normally}

\definemakeup[custom]

\startcustommakeup
\startlocalfootnotes
  This footnote \footnote{does not}
\placelocalfootnotes
\stoplocalfootnotes
\stopcustommakeup

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks, this basically solves the problem for me, but it feels like a bit of a hack. I'm still hoping to see a way to make normal footnotes work.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the `localfootnote` answer by @sztruks, it's possible to add `\placelocalfootnotes` into the footer to approximate normal behavior. It's also possible to add `\startlocalfootnote` outside of the makeup so that footnotes are applied to multiple makeup pages.

```
\setuppapersize[S6][S6]
\starttext

This footnote \footnote{appears normally}

\definemakeup[custom][footerstate=normal]

\setupfootertexts[\placelocalfootnotes][]

\startlocalfootnotes

\startcustommakeup
  This footnote \footnote{now appears}
\stopcustommakeup

\startcustommakeup
  This footnote \footnote{also appears and is incremented}
\stopcustommakeup

\stoplocalfootnotes

\stoptext
```